# Docker PHP Cron Use ENV Variables

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, cron, environment-variables

I am running a PHP background script in on a docker on Amazon ECS. The file I have executign in my cron.d looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

#For Uploading Files
*/2 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.sh

# Mandatory blank line
```

And then in my script I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.profile 

php dosomething.php
```

And inside my php file, its simply:

```
<?php

if(getenv('sometext')){
   echo getenv('sometext');
} else {
   echo 'ENV does not exist'
}
```

If I log into my docker container and I run the script from the command line, it works! But if I run it from, it fails because the env variable are never read. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you expecting this environment variables to be coming from?

Comment: script.sh is a (bash) shell script, but in your crontab it is called ('interpreted') by php!  Also, what is 'root' doing there -- is that a command?

Comment: If you can `chmod 750 script.sh`, you could just do `*/2 * * * * /path/to/script.sh` in your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

A shell command can get environment variables:

`xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "export %q\n" "$@"' -- < /proc/1/environ`

Add it to a script file (eg /data/env.sh):

```
xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "export %q\n" "$@"' -- < /proc/1/environ > /etc/environment
```

your cron.d will looks like:

```
echo "*/2 * * * * root /data/env.sh ; . /etc/environment;/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script.sh"
```